# How to get compressed data using InnoDB and ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am storing long json strings in a mysql table and I have created the table using :

```
ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=8
```

The following settings are also returned for the DB:

```
innodb_file_format = Barracuda (SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_file_per_table';)
innodb_file_per_table = ON (SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_file_format';)
```

The field type is set to mediumtext.

So far, I think I have followed every steps in the book.

However, when the data is inserted in the table, there is no change in the rows average length.

```
SELECT AVG( LENGTH( json_field) ) FROM mytable
```

The commande above still returns the same average length as before switching to ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED

I also use the standard INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(...) command and do not use COMPRESS() on the values.

What is it that I am missing to actually reduce the rows length?

Thanks for your insights on this.

UPDATE:
Please disregard my question as comparing the compressed table  total size with its non compressed version shows that the size has decreased significantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compression works on a lower level (page and (or) Btree node). `LENGTH()` returns the actual length of the (uncompressed) string.

You can use Information Schema to get some insight of how good compression is working for you.

- [Using the Compression Information Schema Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-information-schema-examples-compression-sect.html)

Further reading

- [How Compression Works for InnoDB Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-compression-internals.html)

Comment: So far the ratio (table size)/(number of lines) seems to be returning the same value as before. What command or test should I proceed in order to check if the compression is actually working in my InnoDB environment ? Thank you.

Comment: Please disregard my last comment, as comparing the compressed table  total size with its non compressed version shows that the size has decreased significantly.

Comment: See the update. Also you can look at the idb file sizes for compressed and uncompressed formats for the same etalon workload. E.g. see [Testing InnoDB “Barracuda” format with compression](http://www.percona.com/blog/2008/04/23/testing-innodb-barracuda-format-with-compression/).